# Conditionally show/hide html area in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, conditional-statements

I need to show and hide different areas of my ASP.NET page using C#.
When a user click the first radio button, I want my ASP.NET html to show the first paragraph and hide the second paragraph, and when the user click the second radio button, I want my ASP.NET html to show the second paragraph.

Here's my html code.

---

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="P1">Show First Paragraph</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="P2">Show Second Paragraph</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>


    <br />
    This is my 1st Paragraph.<br />
    <br />


    <br />
    This is my 2nd Paragraph.<br />
    <br />        

</div>
</form>
```

---

So, when the user click the first radio button labelled "Show First Paragraph", I want my page to display the first paragraph with the text "This is my 1st Paragraph." and hide the second paragraph with the text "This is my 2nd Paragraph" and vice versa.

Can someone show me the correct C# event code to accomplish this?

Comment: I googled using your title and found several articles that would do what you are asking.  What have you done so far and how is it failing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for doing this server side and not client side?

Comment: I always thought coding on the server side is better because some visitors can turn-off javascript on their browsers, also I won't have many visitors coming to my site anyway so I'm not worried about the webserver load. I might be wrong but this is what I read from some computer books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an OnSelectedIndexChanged event and also set it to AutoPostBack so that when you select a radio button, it posts back to the server. Then put your paragraphs inside Panels or literals.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="P1">Show First Paragraph</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="P2">Show Second Paragraph</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<br />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Visible="false" runat="server">
This is my 1st Paragraph.<br />
</asp:Panel>


<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" Visible="false" runat="server">
This is my 2nd Paragraph.<br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in your code, you write the event called:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = Panel2.Visible = false;
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "P1")
        Panel1.Visible = true;
    else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "P2")
        Panel2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even know anything about Panels.

Comment: I didn't know how to mark this question as answered but I just found it out... lol